# What are risks of updating JRE for a desktop application on Windows

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, java-8, java-7

I'm planning to update the JRE to the latest version for Java application on windows. The application runs on windows 7 and JRE 7u17.

While I updated it without any issues. I just have these two questions:

Are there risks I should consider while upgrading? Is there a better way to test if the application still runs the same as on JRE7.

Thanks in advance,
Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no risk but there are things to take care of while upgrading from 7 -> 8

In my personal experience I found following things

In my personal experience I had to update all the frameworks which deal with class level operations (spring, tapestry-plastic, etc.. ) and some of them had API changes as well making a huge change in code base

apart from language side there are some changes in VM too, for example: metaspace is introduced and no more permgen space, some stuff from permgen moved to heap, so you might have to re-tune your JVM, there are other things in new JVM you could take advantage of as well